# Cloning/Merging Circles in Google+

Tags: google-plus

Google+'s Circle's feature is a fun way to organize your contacts. Like of Facebook lists, only better. That said, it's not so fun the nth time you do it. Starting some scratch each time you want to create a new circle can get old really fast. Anybody know a way to clone and merge circles?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be a one click option to clone a circle but you can do it by following these steps:

- Click on a circle
- In the pop up window click the link named `View circle in tab`
  [image: PlusOne circles]
- In the top right hand corner select `More options` > `Select All`
  [image: PlusOne SelectAll]
- Everyone who is the circle will be highlighted blue.
- You can then drag all of these people in to a new or existing circle.

Comment: Good tip Barry - the terminology is slightly out of date now (always will be with Google!) - go to Circles, click a circle, then Actions -> Select all, then drag the highlighted people into a new or existing circle.

Comment: I did as described, was told that I'd reached my daily limit so no movement, no merger occurred at all -- despite the fact I hadn't added anyone in more than a week. Even adding one person, in the whole of a week's time, often results in getting such message as "reached limit", just for one person, in more than a week.

Comment: @Viplavah: I've seen that. It's a bug. Use the "Feedback" tool to report it.